# How to Implement recursion upto N levels Having array of objects at each level in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I want to implement recursion for the json given in this link 
[Check JSON Here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ba857deadfc54c309d27bd8a658453ce) my recursion solution is only working for one level so please suggest me the so solution so that I can work up to N-levels.

I have written a recursive function given below but its only working upto one level.

```
Report.GetSections = function(Section1) {
  let TempSectionItem = [];
  let TempAllSection = [];

  let sortOrder = 0;
  let id = Section1.id;
  let parentId = Section1.parentId;
  let title = Section1.label;
  sortOrder = Section1.SortOrder;
  let SectionType = Section1.sectionType;

  if (Section1.sections.length === 0) {
    let TempSectionItem = [];
    let allsection = [];
    let tempsection1 = [];
    let tempsection = new Section(id, title, parentId, SectionType, sortOrder, TempSectionItem, allsection);
    tempsection1.push(tempsection);
    return tempsection1;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < Section1.sections.length; i++) {

    var tempsection = new Section(id, title, parentId, SectionType, sortOrder, TempSectionItem, Report.GetSections(Section1.sections[i]));
    TempAllSection.push(tempsection);

  }

  return TempAllSection;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the recursive solution for the above Question.

```
  class Section {
  constructor(id, title, parentId, sectionType, sortOrder, sectionItem, section) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.sectionType = sectionType;
    this.section = section;
    this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    this.SectionItems = sectionItem;

  }
}
```

Here is the recursive function:

```
  Report.GetSections = function (Section1) {
    let TempSectionItem = [];let sortOrder = 0;
    let id = Section1.id;
    let parentId = Section1.parentId;
    let title = Section1.label;
    sortOrder = Section1.sortOrder;
    let SectionType = Section1.sectionType;
if (Section1.sections.length === 0) {
      let allsection = [];
      let tempsection = new Section(id, title, parentId, SectionType, sortOrder, TempSectionItem, allsection);
      return tempsection;
    }

    let TempLevelSections=[];
    for (let i = 0; i < Section1.sections.length; i++) {
      TempLevelSections.push(Report.GetSections(Section1.sections[i]));
    }
    var section=new Section(id, title, parentId, SectionType, sortOrder, TempSectionItem, TempLevelSections);
    return section;
  }
```